# Plot multiple bar graphs of lists of lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists of lists like these.

```
list1=[[0,1],[1,2.5],[2,3],[3,5.6]]
list2=[[0,2],[2,5],[3,7]]
```

I need to have a bar plot which would compare both lists. The x-axis should have the 1st integer of each element of list1 (`0,1,2,3` etc.). The bars should be side by side and depict the 2nd number of each element of each list.

I have tried the following, but can't seem to separate the graphs. The bars are plotted on top of each other.

```
plt.bar(*zip(*list1))
plt.bar(*zip(*list2))
```

Expected output is to have the bars side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually shift the bars and play with the width so that they appear next to each other. E.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = [[0,1],[1,2.5],[2,3],[3,5.6]]
list2 = [[0,2],[2,5],[3,7]]

x1,y1 = zip(*list1)
x2,y2 = zip(*list2)
plt.bar(np.array(x1)-0.15, y1, width = 0.3)
plt.bar(np.array(x2)+0.15, y2, width = 0.3)
#setting the xticks. Note x1 and x2 are tuples, thus + is concatenation
plt.xticks(range(min(x1+x2), max(x1+x2)+1)) 
plt.show()
```

results in:
[image: plot_result]

(Note that this code supposes integer x values as in the example.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `pandas`:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst), 
                    columns=['idx', i]).set_index('idx')
          for i,lst in enumerate([list1,list2])]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

df.plot.bar()
```

[image]